# Loopback and Ionic 2 (third-party login)

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, loopback

I do not see how to get the loopback authentication token once the connection is made with google.

Let me explain the auth workflow, which may help you understand my problem with 3rd party auth:

1. User's browser initiates auth, is redirected to auth provider, and then is returned to the success callback URL.
2. API code receives evidence of auth and find or creates the user in the database.
3. API code creates an AuthToken for this new user.
4. AuthToken is returned to client that initiated the auth request.
5. AuthToken is stored in memory or local storage to facilitate future calls to the API.

What native cordova plugin to use to get the token from the callback URL ?

The InAppBrowser plugin is deprecated as of ionic-native@1.3.8.